# Fundamentals for login with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have search a lot for how to login with python requests but everybody is doing in another way. Can someone please explain how to login with requests for this url http://weborder2.givi.it/home.

Comment: Chances are pretty good that they're using a session cookie to track whether you're logged in or not. `requests` fortunately supports session objects which will preserve session parameters and cookies between requests. Here's the documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: It's also worth noting that you might need to send along some CSRF token (maybe) in your POST body. I'd encourage you to try a login from your browser while watching the network tab and note what the POST body is. Use that as a bse, and you can pare down what you don't need after getting it working.

Comment: Can you show me an example of code for that url.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not what StackOverflow is for. Please come up with some code yourself and report back. The docs I linked are extremely helpful and filled with examples. Some tips on modifying your question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What should i send in cookie parameter? and every header that server send on post i should send also that within user and pass?

Answer (score 1):

First we should create a session (some kind of emulating a headless browser, as an session object will always store the cookies, session ids, headers, anything releated to a real user session)

Then should open the website (as simulating that you reaching the login page, its important because of cookies)

To see the whole process open a Developer console in Chrome, and reproduce the whole login process, and watch the Networking tab, what kind of requests made by our browser, find releated to the login, and there you will find the required payload by the login site.

Some of them should be parsed, as can't figured out (hashes, form-date and data, its depends on the website)
In our case `form date` should be parsed with lxml.html (you could search for it in the Elements page of developer console, and gather its' xpath

The code below reproducing the whole process as you doing in your browser

```
import requests
import lxml.html

session = requests.Session()

login_page = session.get('http://weborder2.givi.it/home')
form_date = lxml.html.fromstring(login_page.content).xpath('//*[@id="_58_fm"]/input[1]')[0]

data = {'_58_formDate': form_date,
        '_58_saveLastPath': 'false',
        '_58_redirect': '',
        '_58_doActionAfterLogin': 'false',
        '_58_login': your_login_name,
        '_58_password': your_password,
        '_58_rememberMe': 'false'}

session.post('http://weborder2.givi.it/home?p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Flogin', data = data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click => inspect element on the form. It's a POST form
So try something like this (not tested though)

```
r = requests.post('http://weborder2.givi.it/home', data = {'_58_login':'yourlogin', '_58_password': 'yourpassword'})
```

Comment: I have tried but doesn't work. Try to inspect and see the hidden inputs may be i should send more information or headers.